# Running .py files

Tags: python, pyqt

I have .ui, .py and .pyc files generated. Now, when I edit the .py file, how will it reflect changes in the .ui file? How do I connect .the ui and .py files together as QT designer allows only .ui files for running purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit the generated .py file. Create another .py file for the Python code you need to write. This module should load the UI. This would also be the module to run, if these are the only files in the project. See a tutorial from here: http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

the .py file generated from pyuic is not supposed to be edited by the user, best way it is intended to use is to subclass the class in .py file into your own class and do the necessary changes in your class..